# 12.04 to 13.04 goes black. Why?

Tags: 13.04

I have an HP G60-445DX Notebook PC running Ubuntu 12.04. How can I check to see if I can upgrade to 13.04? I tried to install it once before and my screen stayed black so I reinstalled 12.04? New to Linux/Ubuntu! Does it have anything to do with the 32/64 thing and what is that?

Answer (score 0):

12.04 is a Long Term Service (LTS) release, meaning that it is a stable version for which you will get package updates for a long period. By default you'll only get a notice for a release upgrade when a new LTS comes out; that will be 14.04, btw.

If you want to upgrade already to one of the intermediate releases the easiest way to do it is using the upgrade manager GUI. [This guide](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-to-ubuntu-12-10) walks you through the process.

The 32/64 bit thing refers to the CPU architecture, you can read more details at [Wikipaedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing), but in essence you have operating systems for both architectures. When you perform an Ubuntu upgrade you wont be changing this particular nature of the operating system.